# Reading from a socket in a while loop

Tags: java, sockets, loops, inputstream

I want to implement the following functionality

```
while (true)
{
if client sends something 
process it

else wait till something is send }
```

I have tried the following but it didn't work , it process one thing and then stop working 
can anyone help me?
I have searched for such a case here but I didn't find anything .  I would appreciate it if anyone can give an example of how to read from the socket inside a while loop as in the above description .

```
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToclient =new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            while (true){
                if ((request=inFromClient.readLine())!=null){


                        System.out.println("ser "+request);         
                        msg1= new msgs();
                        if(msg1.IsListReq(request))
                        {
                               System.out.println("Ser :List req");



                               for (int i = 0; i <listOfFiles.length ; i++) 
                               {

                                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
                                     {

                                         files[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                                     }

                               }

                                //prepare the respones
                                msg1.MakeFileListResponse (files);
                                outToclient.writeBytes(msg1.getMsg()+'\n');

                        } // end of processing List Request
                    } // end of first if statement
                 } end of while loop
```

Comment: Please apply proper formatting!

Comment: I am not sure where your curly braces are closed

Comment: Please rewrite your question into a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/). We cannot compile this. Also, please re-indent so we can read it.

Comment: I'm sorry I will edit it now

Answer (score 0):

You should have a condition to break your while loop or it will loop forever and your program will crash. This could be the problem you have.

Comment: but I want it to run as long as there is an input from the server

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you have an infinite loop.  This differs from "read as long as there is input available" in that it will continue to read after input is no longer available.

Try something like this:

```
do
{
    request = inFromClient.readLine();
    if (request != null)
    {
        // do stuff.
    }
} while (request != null);
```

The example above will stop reading when input is no longer available from the input stream.

For information about java and sockets check out the [Oracle Java Socket Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html).
The work you describe will reside on a server.

Comment: I don't no when the input will be available or how many times it will be available so how can I solve it?

Comment: For that, you will need to read a java sockets tutorial.  basically you will listen on a socket and react when a message is received.

Comment: Can you please give me a link for such tutorial ? I honestly don't know what to type on google to get this tutorial . I have done socket programming in C before but I don't know how to do it with java